# CakePHP 3.10 adding a Form field with '_id' in name, automatically makes it a select field

Tags: cakephp

CakePHP 3.10 adding a Form field with '_id' in name, automatically makes it a select field. I want to know if this is something that is done in our App specifically by previous developer and if so, how/where would I look?

Alternatively, if it's a CakePHP thing, where can I get documentation on it?

Controller:

```
public function add()
{
    $building = $this->Buildings->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        //code for after form submission
    }

    $this->set(compact('building'));
}
```

View:

```
 <div>        
        <?= $this->Form->create($building) ?>
        <fieldset>
            <legend><?= __('Add Building') ?></legend>
            <?php
                echo $this->Form->control('test_id'); <!-- this field type will be a select field -->               
                echo $this->Form->control('name');
            ?>
        </fieldset>
        <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
        <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: yes, it's a cakephp feature  https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-select-checkbox-and-radio-controls

Comment: The form helper docs are a bit messy... you can find it mentioned in the "Creating Form Controls" section (https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-form-controls), where it says "_If you want to create a select form field while using a belongsTo (or hasOne) relation [...]_"

Comment: I see you have linked v4, but i am using v3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read [this V3](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers/form.html#namespace-Cake%5CView%5CHelper) documentation you can see:

[image]
[https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers/form.html#namespace-Cake\View\Helper](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers/form.html#namespace-Cake%5CView%5CHelper)

So, the cause of this is because cakephp understand you have a belongsTo or hasOne association between `Buildings` model and `Test` model.

If you have a test_id column in buildings table, you are saying to cakephp that tests table **has one** or **has many** building/s.

you can force the type of Form Helper using the condition:

```
$this->Form->control('test_id', ['type' => 'text']);
```

Extra note: when you have this case you could use [virtual fields](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-fields) to show what is the test_id that the Building belongs.
For example: you could show the concatenation of the test name and author name (assuming these two fields exist in the test table) like:

Into TestEntity.php

```
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class Test extends Entity
{
    protected function _getTestIndicator()
    {
        return $this->name . '  ' . $this->author_name;
    }
}
```

Into the view:

```
echo $user->test_indicator;
```

Comment: This has been very insightful